# The application requires Unity3d permission

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game created on Unity3d at startup requires 2 resolutions:

**android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE** and **android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS**

The game uses Google Play Services and 3 third-party assets from the Asset Store, so let's say **GET_ACCOUNTS** if I understand correctly it's used for achiviements, leaderboard, etc. But why I need access to **READ_PHONE_STATE** I did not understand. These game permissions asked the game before installing and configuring Google Play Services, and all 3 third-party assaults were purely internal gaming (first for background, second for controlling touch and third for object pooling). I checked the Android Manifest in the root directory of the game project and did not find in it a single mention of **android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE** or **android.permission.GET_AACCONTS**. Can you tell me that there is something in these 3 third-party asses that refers to these functions? Or is the Google SDK referring to such things by default?

Comment: "Get Accounts" is a default if you're using leaderboards, achievements, etc.. READ_PHONE_STATE is a default used by Unity so that it can pause the game when you get a call, etc.

Comment: Brandon Miller Thanks Very Much. Then it is strange that for this Google Play requires the creation of a policy of confidentiality.